# how to get min max in timestamp

Tags: mysql, timestamp, max, min

I have table data and need to get a result set containing a row for the max(timestamp) for id. where timestamp between parameter 
The data sample would look like: [example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAVxP.png)

I can't figure out how to get a row for the max(timestamp) for each id and between parameter.

```
select id,
        tgl,
         max(case when tgl::timestamp between '2018-08-01 06:00'::timestamp and '2018-08-02 06:00'::timestamp 
        then tgl::timestamp else null end) clock
        from tb_raw_pola_internal
        where id = '0023817'
        group by 1, 2
        order by 1,2 asc
        limit 1
```

and the result is:

[image]

My result set should clock in `2018-08-02 02:05:00`

Who can be my hero? :) thanks before

Answer (score 0):

You are doing group by on aggregation column as well. Try below code :

```
    select id,
    tgl,
     max(case when tgl::timestamp between '2018-08-01 06:00'::timestamp 
     and '2018-08-02 06:00'::timestamp 
    then tgl::timestamp else null end) clock
    from tb_raw_pola_internal
    where id = '0023817'
    group by 1;
```